ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error (WSL)
I am currently trying to mount 2 VDIs and compare them using WSL. However, I am unable to access certain folders, I am assuming due to permissions. These are VDIs that I have created in order to get a list of files created after installation of programs.
I've already edited wsl.conf to the following based on previous questions asked. However, I am still not able to view the contents of the folder.
[boot]
systemd=true

[automount]
enabled=true
root = /mnt/
options  = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11,uid=1000,gid=1000"


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
